# Differance in installing a rom from a different country

Tags: rom

What are the differences in ROMs that are from different countries? Like for the S4 GT-i9500 4.3, There are some many country versions. Is it just localization differences? or something at system level?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you install different countries ROM, you will get some different app that follows in that country region.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's OK to flash stock ROM from another country. BUT, take note that it may have different languages, and a different baseband/modem. Having a different baseband can cause network issues (or a very hot phone), but you can flash a baseband that works for your country.