# My Nexus 4 shutdown randomly?

Tags: nexus-4, reboot

I'm living in India. Last year I bought my Nexus 4 in the US.

For a couple of months now my device is getting quite hot, and shuts down randomly. I have done a factory reset 2 times, but no use of that: the shutdown continues.

This mostly happens when I'm on 3g, but not when I lock the device to 2g. The problem started about 5 months after purchase, so it didn't exist from the start.

Has anyone experienced this issue? Can anything be done to solve it?

Comment: I guess after the factory-reset you've re-installed all your apps? One of them could be responsible for described instability. If the "indicators" (e.g. "device getting hot") start immediately, you could try tracking that down by not installing all your apps at once, but split that into "halfes" (i.e. first install the first 50%, observe, if the problem does not re-appear install the next 25% and observe, and so on. If it starts with the first 50%, try again with the other 50% *instead*. If it doesn't happen with those, it's pretty likely one of the "other half" is the culprit.

Comment: Thanks Izzy, I have done this test already and conclude that the problem not belongs to the apps that i have installed. probably im using 2g data connectivity, when I switch to 3g the device gets so hot and after some moments it gets shutdown.

Comment: I was pretty sure something would turn up this way. So the problem even exists without any additional apps installed, directly after a factory-reset? In that (rare) case, that leaves just a hardware (or OS) issue. I'd say pay a visit to your dealer, your device should still be under warranty.

Comment: Just a [different pointer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/71416/16575): Did you flash something manually, or maybe have a device built/configured for a different country? Your mentioning of 3g causing the issue would match here.

Comment: Hello, Last week I updated my nexus4 from Google for Android 4.4.3, and from that moment itself, the shutdown bug partially reduced by getting shutdown 1 time for three days.

Answer (score 1):

its an hardware issue because of network kernal...
When I replaced the board and now the phone works fine.